# Does $y_n=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+..+\frac{1}{2n}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: analysis, limits

I have to show whether $y_n=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+..+\frac{1}{2n}$ is convergent or divergent. I tried using the squeeze theorem to prove it was convergent. So what I did was 
bound ${y_n}$ in between $\frac{-1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$. That is $\frac{-1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+..+\frac{1}{2n} \leq \frac{1}{n}$ Since we also proved earlier that $lim\frac{1}{n}=0$ and $lim\frac{-1}{n}= -lim\frac{-1}{n}=0$ It follows by the squeeze theorem that $lim(y_n)=0$. Would this be correct?

Edit: This what I have now.
Well this what I get so far that $ \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}≥ \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k+1}$ Hence its divergent. I think it works since  $ \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k+1}=\frac{1}{(n+1)+1}+\frac{1}{(n+2)+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n+1}$ ≤ $ \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}= \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n} $.

Comment: I think the right half of your squeeze is wrong. For $n=2$, it gives $(1/3)+(1/4)\le1/2$.

Comment: oh I did prove that $lim(\frac{b}{n})=0$ where $b\in\mathbb{R}$. I think I can try using that.

Comment: oh ok so its divergent what if I index n such that $y_n=\frac{1}{n_1+1}+\frac{1}{n_2+2}+..+\frac{1}{n_k^2}$ such that $n=n_1=...=n_k$ Then it follows that  $y_n=\frac{1}{n_1+1}+\frac{1}{n_2+2}+..+\frac{1}{n_k^2}$ < $\frac{1}{n_1+1}+\frac{1}{n_2+1}+..+\frac{1}{n_k+1}$. Hence it is divergent.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you.

Comment: Oops Ill should redo it like this Let $y_n=\frac{1}{n_1+1}+\frac{1}{n_2+2}+..+\frac{1}{n_k^2}$ where $n=n_1=...=n_k$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus $y_n=\frac{1}{n_1+1}+\frac{1}{n_2+2}+..+\frac{1}{n_k^2}\geq \frac{1}{n_1+1}$. This sequence is divergent.

Comment: Why does $y_n\ge1/(n_1+1)$ imply the sequence is divergent? After all, $1/(n_1+1)\to0$ as $n_1\to\infty$.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing I think. So I already know its  divergent but to show it is divergent I have to show $(y_n)$ is bigger then another divergent sequence?

Comment: That's the usual way.

Comment: I think that the recent change of the question ($n^2$ changed to $2n$) is inappropriate.  The old version was already answered, and it has been removed.  It would be better to ask the new question as a new question, in a separate thread (with a link to this one).  (Even though apparently the original version was posted by mistake, it became its own question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that

$$\gamma_n=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+..+\frac{1}{n}- \ln(n) \,,$$ is convergent then your sequence is exactly

$$\gamma_{n^2}-\gamma_n+ \ln(n) \,.$$

As $\gamma_{n^2}-\gamma_n \to 0$ and $\ln(n) \to \infty$ it follows that your sequence diverges to $\infty$.

---

**Edit** With the change, your sequence is

$$\gamma_{2n}-\gamma_n+\ln(2n)-\ln(n)= \gamma_{2n}-\gamma_n+\ln(2)$$

which is convergent.

**A simpler solution**
your sequence is also

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}$$

which is the Riemann Sum associated to $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ on $[1,2]$ with $x_k=x_k^*=1+\frac{k}{n}$.

Both solutions also Yield $\ln(2)$ as the limit.

**Third solution**

$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+..+\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{2}+..+\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}$$

is a well known identity, pretty standard induction problem. Then you can use the Alternating Series Test.

Comment: I have made a bad mistake in the problem. The last term $\frac{1}{n^2}$ is supposed to be $\frac{1}{2n}$

Comment: @user60887 Gave new solutions to the new problem...

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning would be correct if $y_n<\frac{1}{n}$, which is not true. The sequence actually diverges. To prove it, we use the fact that for $k\in[\![1,n-1]\!]$,
\begin{align}
    \frac{1}{kn+1}+\frac{1}{kn+2}+...+\frac{1}{kn+n} &\geq \frac{1}{kn+n}+\frac{1}{kn+n}+...+\frac{1}{kn+n} \\
         &\geq \frac{n}{n(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k+1}
\end{align}

Then, we can rewrite $y_n$ using such partial sums:
\begin{align}
    y_n&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{kn+1}+\frac{1}{kn+2}+...+\frac{1}{kn+n}\\
        &\geq\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+1}
\end{align}
This sum diverges when $n\to\infty$, thus $y_n$ also diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$\frac1{k+1} 
\le \int_k^{k+1} \frac{dt}{t} 
\le \frac1{k}
$.

Summing from $n+1$ to $n^2$,
$\sum_{k=n}^{n^2-1}\frac1{k+1} 
\le \sum_{k=n}^{n^2-1}\int_k^{k+1} \frac{dt}{t} 
\le \sum_{k=n}^{n^2-1}\frac1{k}
$,
or
$\sum_{k=n+1}^{n^2}\frac1{k} 
\le \int_n^{n^2} \frac{dt}{t} 
\le \sum_{k=n}^{n^2-1}\frac1{k}
$.

Using the right-hand inequality,
$
\sum_{k=n+1}^{n^2}\frac1{k}
=-\frac1{n}+\frac1{n^2}+\sum_{k=n}^{n^2-1}\frac1{k}
\ge -\frac1{n}+\frac1{n^2}+\int_n^{n^2} \frac{dt}{t} 
>-\frac1{n}+ \ln(n^2)-\ln(n)
= \ln(n)-\frac1{n}
$
which diverges as $n \to \infty$.

If we use the left-hand inequality,
$
\sum_{k=n+1}^{n^2}\frac1{k}
\le \ln(n)
$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to proceed using the Riemann sum idea

$$ y_n=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+..+\frac{1}{2n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+i}$$

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+\frac{i}{n}} \longrightarrow_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x}=\dots.$$

Answer (score 0):

The sum
$$y_n:=\sum_{k=n+1}^{k=n^2}\frac 1 k = \Psi(n^2)-\Psi(n+1),$$
where $\Psi(x):= \frac {\Gamma'(x)} {\Gamma(x)} \sim \ln  \left( x \right) -\frac 1 2\,{x}^{-1}-\frac1 {12}\,{x}^{-2}+O \left( {x}^{-4}
 \right)
$ as $x \to \infty $. In view of this $y_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: True, but unlikely to help OP any time in the next two or three years.

Answer (score 0):

If
$y_n=\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
y_{n}-y_{n-1}
&=\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}
-\sum\limits_{k=n}^{2n-2}\frac{1}{k}\\
&=\frac1{2n}+\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{n}\\
&=\frac1{2n}+\frac1{2n-1}-(\frac1{2n}+\frac1{2n})\\
&=\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n}\\
&<\frac1{2n-2}-\frac1{2n}\\
&=\frac12(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n})\\
\end{array}
$

and
$y_{n}-y_{n-1}
> 0$.

Summing from
$n+1$ to $m$,

$y_m-y_n
=\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^m (y_{k}-y_{k-1})
> 0
$
and
$y_m-y_n
=\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^m (y_{k}-y_{k-1})
<\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^m \frac12(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1{k})
= \frac12(\frac1{n}-\frac1{m})
< \frac1{2n}
$.

By the Cauchy criteria,
$y_n$ converges,
without showing what the limit is.